# Group by pandas to get path from source to end destination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have the following table

| Path ID | Lane ID | Customer | Source | Destination | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Mumbai | Chicago | Berlin | Ship |
| 1 | 2 | Mumbai | Berlin | Mumbai | Air |
| 2 | 1 | Mumbai | Chicago | Berlin | Air |
| 2 | 2 | Mumbai | Berlin | Dubai | Air |
| 2 | 3 | Mumbai | Dubai | Mumbai | Ship |

I want the following table

| Path ID | Source | Site2 | Site3 | Destination | Lane1 Mode | Lane2 Mode | Lane3 Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chicago | Berlin |  | Mumbai | Ship | Air |  |
| 2 | Chicago | Berlin | Dubai | Mumbai | Air | Air | Ship |

How do I go about getting this table? I feel like `groupby` is obviously required but what after that? Not sure how to proceed from there. The dataset is really big so it also needs to be efficient. Any pointers would help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `drop` irrelevant columns. Then as @LiamRoberts notes, `pivot` will get us in the right shape. Then fix the "Destination" column with `stack` + `groupby` + `last`. Finally, fix the column names.

```
s = df.drop(columns='Customer').pivot(index=['Path ID'], columns=['Lane ID'])
s['Dest'] = s['Destination'].stack().groupby(level=0).last()
s = s.drop(columns='Destination').reset_index()
s.columns = [f'{c1}{c2}' for c1, c2 in s.columns]
s = (s.rename(columns={'Source1':'Source', 'Source2':'Site2', 
                       'Source3':'Site3', 'Dest':'Destination',
                      'Mode1':'Lane1 Mode', 'Mode2':'Lane2 Mode', 
                       'Mode3':'Lane3 Mode'})[['Path ID','Source','Site2','Site3','Destination',
                                               'Lane1 Mode','Lane2 Mode','Lane3 Mode']])
```

Output:

```
   Path ID   Source   Site2  Site3 Destination Lane1 Mode Lane2 Mode    Lane3 Mode  
0        1  Chicago  Berlin    NaN      Mumbai       Ship        Air           NaN  
1        2  Chicago  Berlin  Dubai      Mumbai        Air        Air          Ship
```

Comment: I was getting `ValueError: Expected length of x rows, received array of length 1` in `.pivot()` function. When I removed the square brackets around `Lane ID`, your solution gave me what I wanted. :) Thanks! Didn't know some of the functionality you used but nice to learn

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're actually pivoting the Lane Id and indexing with the Path Id. This should get you most of the way.

```
df.pivot(index="Path ID", columns="Lane ID")
```